# Drum machine with "recorder"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am half way through the drum machine project on freecodecamp and just came across a finished work built by someone [here](https://codepen.io/mgazge/full/yqvBXa) with the record and playback features. However, this feature only plays back the musical notes captured at the unchangeable tempo. If I click the keypads at various rhythms, this pattern won't be captured. For example, if I click "Q" keypad 10 times in two seconds and then hit "W" keypad twice at the speed of 1 hit per second on recording mode, this hit versus time pattern isn't recorded. Does anyone have any idea on how this can be achieved?

```js
playSound(e) {
    //console.log('In playSound power = ' + this.props.power);
    if (this.props.power) {
        const sound = document.getElementById(this.props.keyTrigger);
        sound.currentTime = 0;
        sound.play();

        const button = document.getElementById(this.props.id);
        button.style.backgroundColor = "#00c7ec";
        setTimeout(() => { button.style.backgroundColor = '#012839'; }, 500);
        this.props.updateDisplay(this.props.id, 500);

        if (this.props.){
            // record key in array
            recordArray.push(this.props.keyCode);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like the recordArray is a fixed tempo somehow. I think you'd need to rework more than just this one function to make it higher resolution.

Comment: Is there any approach to do that? any function that would do the work?